# The correlation with groupby returns all NaN values Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, correlation

I have a dataframe like this (the real DF has 94 columns and 40 rows):

| NAME | TIAS | EFGA | SOE | KERA | CODE | SURVIVAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SOAP corp | `1.391164e+10` | `1.265005e+10` | `0.000000e+00` | `186522000.0` | 366 | 21 |
| NiANO inc | `42673.0` | 0.0 | 0.0 | 42673.0 | 366 | 3 |
| FFS jv | `9.523450e+05` | NaN | NaN | `8.754379e+09` | 737 | 4 |
| KELL Corp | `1.045967e+07` | `9.935970e+05` | `0.000000e+00` | NaN | 737 | 4 |
| Os inc | `7.732654e+10` | `4.046270e+07` | `1.391164e+10` | `8.754379e+09` | 737 | 4 |

I need to make a correlation for each group in frame by CODE. The target value is SURVIVAL column.
I tried this:

```
df = df.groupby('CODE').corr()[['SURVIVAL']]
```

but it returns something like this:

| CODE |  | SURVIVAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 366 | TIAS | NaN |
|  | EFGA | NaN |
|  | SOE | NaN |
|  | KERA | NaN |
|  | SURVIVAL | NaN |
| 737 | TIAS | NaN |
|  | EFGA | NaN |
|  | SOE | NaN |
|  | KERA | NaN |
|  | SURVIVAL | NaN |

Why is it NaN in all columns?
I tried to fill NaNs in DataFrame with mean values before making a correlations:

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

or drop them but it does not work.

But when I make the correlation for all dataframe without any modifications like this:

```
df.corr()[['SURVIVAL']]
```

everything works good and I have correlations, not NaNs.

All types are float64 and int64.
Is there the way to get correlation by group without NaNs? I have no idea why it works on all dataframe but does not work in groups.

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
df = df.groupby('CODE')[['SURVIVAL']].corr()
```

Comment: It doesn`t work :(

Comment: Have you tried after filling NA?, And also try after adding all the numerical columns to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
survival_corr = lambda x: x.corrwith(x['SURVIVAL'])
by_code = df.groupby('CODE')
by_code.apply(survival_corr)
```